Looking for an alternative to listings and minted
I am an Ubuntu/Fedora user who is trying to represent code in a LaTeX beamer presentation.
I've installed texlive-full on Ubuntu and texlive-scheme-full on Fedora, and tried both the listings and minted packages.
I originally tried the listings package. However, it depends on fonts that apparently aren't installed as part of texlive-full. The resulting code looks absolutely terrible, with really weird spacing.
Next I tried using the minted package. This package depends on something called pygmentize, which again, is not installed part of texlive-full (or, interestingly python3-pygments or pip install pygments).
Ultimately, I don't need syntax colorization, just a fixed with font that follows the spacing that I specify in the .tex file:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{hello world}
    \begin{code}
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
    \end{code}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

I also tried piton as suggested in minted vs. listings: pros and cons but it is causing my CPU to melt itself into slag:
top - 22:25:35 up 1 day,  6:39,  1 user,  load average: 5.94, 4.28, 2.19
Tasks: 409 total,   4 running, 405 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 29.2 us,  4.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.2 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :  63653.6 total,  15315.7 free,   8109.2 used,  41037.9 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:   8192.0 total,   8192.0 free,      0.0 used.  55544.5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
 422496 peter     20   0 1132.5g   1.7g  99424 R 224.3   2.7  14:22.83 code     
 424815 peter     20   0  146652  65408   6272 R  99.7   0.1   8:34.28 pdflatex 
 422685 peter     20   0 1134.2g   1.4g  80000 R  86.7   2.2   7:31.10 code     
 422751 peter     20   0 1132.1g  95472  73600 S  68.8   0.1   5:42.35 code     
 422408 peter     20   0 1132.3g 273108 135324 S  31.9   0.4   2:47.81 code     

Here is a MNWE using the listing package:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      printf("Hello World!");
      return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

which gives me the following warnings:
LaTeX Font: Font shape `OML/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)  using `OML/cmm/m/it' instead
(Font)  for symbol `textless'.

and
LaTeX Font: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)  using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)  for symbol `textbraceleft'.

and the result looks like:

Replacing lstlisting with verbatim in the example above results in


listings just uses standard fonts, pygmentize is a python brogram as you say. but it sounds like you need no package at all and just use \begin{verbatim}....\end{verbatim}

Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same result with verbatim as with Piton. Massive CPU load.

welcome! if I change code to verbatim in your example, it compiles fine. I certainly don't see excessive cpu load. but there is something odd happening if listings doesn't work properly, anyway. can you change code to verbatim, compile the example and post your log?

Turns out that verbatim works fine. But piton leaves a bunch of build artefacts around that appear to confuse LaTeX, and cause the CPU to spike. Starting from scratch solved the problem. Thanks!


I don't see a MNWE (minimum non-working example). 2) My guess is that something is not right with the LaTeX the distributions are providing. To confirm this theory, I would install (at least temporarily) a full version of TeXLive (e.g., 2024), then modify your paths to point to it ahead of the distribution binaries. If the .tex file then builds correctly, it's a latex distribution problem in ubuntu or fedora.


verbatim uses no cpu resources at all (more than normal tex) it uses no external code and is just a font change. Whatever your cpu load is it is probably unrelated to anything you have shown so far,

Can you show your lstlisting example so we can which basic style you choose? Fonts can be changed...

Please also include a screenshot of the result you describe as "absolutely terrible, with really weird spacing" so we have a better chance to guess what result you are actually looking for.

You can keep using listings and change the basicstyle to make the code look more pleasant. Here with a mono-spaced font (other mono-spaced fonts are available if you don't like computer modern):
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      printf("Hello World!");
      return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



I suggest taking a look at the package piton (which requires the use LuaLaTeX).
Here is, for example, the output for your example.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{Piton}[language = C,auto-gobble]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      printf("Hello World!");
      return 0;
    }
\end{Piton}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


